# Add lollipop sticks for point plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I (if possible) add lollipop sticks to point plots?

For instance,

```
plot(1:10, sin(1:10))
```

How do I add a vertical line (lollipop stick) from each of the ten points to the x-axis? Do I need to code a function that draws each stick?

Comment: another one `plot(1:10, sin(1:10), type = 'h'); points(1:10, sin(1:10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `ggplot2` tag, but use a base example, so I'll show both.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sin(1:10))
```

Base plotting uses `'h'` as aplot type, that plots "histogram like" lines see `?plot`. You can then add points on top of that.

```
plot(df$x, df$y, type = 'h')
points(df$x, df$y, pch = 20)
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

`ggplot2` allows you to specify start and end points in `geom_segment`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = 0, xend = x, yend = y)) +
     geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The segments function will do what you want.

```
plot(1:10, sin(1:10))
abline(h=0, lty=2)
segments(1:10, 0, 1:10, sin(1:10))
```

[image: Lollipop Sticks]

Answer (score 0):

Cuz we wldn't want to use `ggalt::geom_lollipop()`:

```
 devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/ggalt")

df <- read.csv(text="category,pct
Other,0.09
South Asian/South Asian Americans,0.12
Interngenerational/Generational,0.21
S Asian/Asian Americans,0.25
Muslim Observance,0.29
Africa/Pan Africa/African Americans,0.34
Gender Equity,0.34
Disability Advocacy,0.49
European/European Americans,0.52
Veteran,0.54
Pacific Islander/Pacific Islander Americans,0.59
Non-Traditional Students,0.61
Religious Equity,0.64
Caribbean/Caribbean Americans,0.67
Latino/Latina,0.69
Middle Eastern Heritages and Traditions,0.73
Trans-racial Adoptee/Parent,0.76
LBGTQ/Ally,0.79
Mixed Race,0.80
Jewish Heritage/Observance,0.85
International Students,0.87", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(scales)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(category, pct), x=pct))
gg <- gg + geom_lollipop(point.colour="steelblue", point.size=3, horizontal=TRUE)
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), labels=percent,
                              breaks=seq(0, 1, by=0.2), limits=c(0, 1))
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL,
                title="SUNY Cortland Multicultural Alumni survey results",
                subtitle="Ranked by race, ethnicity, home land and orientation\namong the top areas of concern",
                caption="Data from http://stephanieevergreen.com/lollipop/")
gg <- gg + theme_minimal(base_family="Arial Narrow")
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.line.y=element_line(color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(r=-5, l=0)))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(30, 4), "pt"))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(margin=margin(b=10)))
gg <- gg + theme(plot.caption=element_text(size=8, margin=margin(t=10)))
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Does it also work for the function that I used as example? It seems that it only works for factors

Comment: the `geom_` uses the same underlying principle as the ggplot2 answer you starred as correct.